# I need a way to remove "dead pages" from an ASP.NET 2.0-4.0 site

Tags: asp.net, refactoring, resharper, code-cleanup, dead-code

I've taken over about 30 projects at a company. Through the years the guy who ran things worked directly on the server. There's tons of dead pages that cause Visual Studio to break.

I have JetBrains Resharper (Latest) and I also have Telerik Full Suite with all their tools.

How can I cull out these dead pages, is there some automated way I can clean out the crap and get these things to build? The sites range from Windows 2003 and IIS to Windows 2008 with IIS.

When we go to build we get 4100 errors and that's quite a bit to just ferret out.

I'd love some ideas, techniques, tools, etc... that might help in this task.

Comment: `Dead pages` - 'dead' how? 404's? The page exists but throws error? What's your definition of a 'dead page'?

Comment: What do you mean by "cause Visual Studio to break"? Compiler gives you an error? Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have ReSharper solution-wide analysis turned on. Go to ReSharper | Options -> Code Inspection | Settings and turn on "Analyze errors in whole solution". You would get an indicator at right bottom of your Visual Studio, it would tell you about different potential errors in your solution. Also unused methods would be colored gray, so you would be able to clean it up when you see it.